# CSS: How do I have an element be inline in one situation but be table-cell in another situation?

Tags: css

TL; DR: I'm looking for a way to display a SPAN element that can achieve the desired behavior showed in the 1st and 3rd pictures below.

Interactive Code: http://jsfiddle.net/53GZe/1/

When selecting text from a block of text, the display needs to be inline, so that no breaks are generated.

---

[image]

---

Now when I try to select multiple elements with the same display: inline: I get this:

---

[image]

---

Because the display is set to inline, it doesn't know how wide to make the `<span>` (the element inserted around the selection to give the custom highlight effect)

So, for the other case, when I set display to table-cell, I get this behavior:

---

[image]

---

Which is wonderful, and kind of neat. Except for that it doesn't work with an inline block of text like in my first example:

---

[image]

---

(notice the breaks before and after the selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use jQuery to search the children of the highlighted div. Then if there are any blocked elements or line breaks, set the `display` property to table-cell.

Or by setting a new CSS rule for the situation, maybe again, by using jQuery to check for the inner elements?

```
.situation1 .highlighted { display:table-cell; }
.situation2 .highlighted { display:inline; }
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Unfortunately, because it's so much javascript generating the .highlighted element, it'll be a bit more work than adding another CSS rule. thanks though!

Comment: Hey, I've just read the full question and realised it's not exactly what you were after. I've updated the answer (and probably will continue as I think of more ideas ;D)

Comment: your jQuery suggestion would be what I do if I implement this right now. =D